# Changing settings on a dart websocket

Tags: websocket, dart

I tried fiddling a little, but seeing that dart uses some wrapping classes internally, i'm not sure how i can set the settings of a socket. Specifically i try to create a low latency websocket-server, so i want to change the TCP_NODELAY flag (are there any other relevant flags/settings for low latency?) .

The code i have now is below. Seeing very high latencies when testing, i think its because of TCP_NODELAY. With a simple node.js socket-server i did mange to get low latencies.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:route/server.dart'; 

var port = 7654; 

void main() {  
  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, port) 
    .then((HttpServer server) { 

      print('listening for connections on $port');

      var router = new Router(server);
      router.serve('/ws').transform(new WebSocketTransformer()).listen(blub);
      router.serve('/').listen((req) {
          req.response..write('foo ${new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}')..close();
        });
    },
    onError: (error) => print("Error starting HTTP server: $error"));
}

void blub(WebSocket ws) { 

  print("@@ $ws");
  ws.listen((obj) {
    ws.add(obj); 
    print("@@ $obj ${new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TCP_NODELAY` [is already enabled by the HttpServer](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/sdk/lib/io/http_impl.dart#L2009).

Comment: Is there a way i can disable it so i can compare? A roundtrip (back and forth) takes 200ms on an otherwise idle server while a node.js socketserver takes 1-2ms over LAN and 20-40ms over WAN. The node.js server comes from [here](http://cjihrig.com/blog/creating-your-own-node-js-websocket-echo-server/). Im doing a decently thorough investigation and it seems something is causing a delay other then congestion or RAM/CPU load.

Comment: See my first version of the anwser that I later replaced by this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20034154/1

Comment: Your first version indeed has the answer to the question (even if the flag is already set) so i'll accept it. Although the changed version is still informative, it still left me to wonder how to change the flag. Thanks for your super fast response :)